# Minimal cross section of an 3D curved channel-- solution in Python?

Tags: python, geometry, interpolation, mesh, differential-equations

Additional to the question asked and answered at: [Minimal surface solution in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16625316/minimal-surface-solution-in-python)

I am looking for the smallest cross section= surface which is able to close an 3D curved channel.
I.e the shape of the *limiting curve in not given, but must additional be determined on the surface of the channel.*

*Input*: sufficient points defining the 3D channel.
*Needed output*: area of this minimal cross section and points defining this surface.

I need to make such an implementation in Python, but up to know I haven't found any web resources on how to to this.
Can anyone point me any resources/examples of such implementation?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide a [mcve], explain what difficulties you are facing.

Comment: Make sure the question is self-contained. At the moment it appears that I need to read the linked content to understand the question.